# How to redirect path to a different folder using mod_rewrite/mod_alias?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, redirect, mod-alias

I have mod_rewrite and mod_alias enabled. I have some csv files saved in /home/ubuntu/csv. Due to reasons, I can't move files to any other folder.

My website url redirects to /var/www/html. So wesbite-url.com would redirect to /var/www/html.

What I want is somehow website-url.com/files/a.csv should redirect to /home/ubuntu/csv/a.csv? Basically I want to access any file, say x, saved in /home/ubuntu/csv via website-url.com/files/x

How do I go about doing this?

I tried the following commands among others:

```
RedirectMatch ^/files/$ /home/ubuntu/portalCsv/
RedirectMatch ^/files/ /home/ubuntu/portalCsv/
Redirect /files/a /home/ubuntu/portalCsv/
```

What is the correct command for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the url part after **/files/** and append it to the Redirect destination

```
RedirectMatch ^/files/(.+)$ /home/ubuntu/portalCsv/$1
```

This will redirect your browser from **/files/foobar** to **/home/ubuntu/portalCsv/foobar** .

if you want to redirect using mod-rewrite,you can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?files/(.+)$ /home/ubuntu/portalCsv/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The url in the browser changed to: 
http://website-url.com/home/ubuntu/portalCsv/a